# What's the word that means "The following assumption is true if it gives the right result"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What's the word that means "I'm assuming this for the time being and upon using the assumption, if I get the correct answer, then it proves that the assumption is true"
Our teacher regularly assumes stuff and use them in a formula and if the result is correct then we know that the assumtion we made is true. He uses a word that sounds something like 'Asphases' but turns out it's not a word as per dictionary so can anyone tell me what he actually means when he says that or if there is another word which has same meaning that would be also great.

Comment: Maybe you should just ask him...?

Comment: Sounds like your teacher might be saying "Assuming that....".  Alternatively you could say "Given that..."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ppl I got the word, it's 'ansatz'

"Ansatz : an initial estimate of the solution to a mathematical or technical problem that is used to guide work to a more precise answer"

As in Merriam-Webster dictionary

Answer (score 5):

I think the word you're looking for (which sounds similar to your *asphases*)  is [**hypothesis**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypothesis):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 a** : an assumption or concession made for the sake of argument
> **b** : an interpretation of a practical situation or condition taken as the ground for action
> **2** : a tentative assumption made in order to draw out and test its logical or empirical consequences
> **3** : the antecedent clause of a conditional statement

In particular, it's sense 2 in your case.

Comment: Yes the assumption of hypotheses and testing to see if you can disprove or confirm them is the basis of the scientific method.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Science can never literally 'confirm' hypotheses, only show they are false.

Comment: Hey thanks for your time. I figured out the word it's 'Ansatz'

Answer (score 1):

If your description is accurate, it's a case of [circular reasoning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning). You can't prove something by assuming it's true and conclude there is no contradiction. This is mathematics, not a sudoku... The opposite, assuming the negation of the original assumption and reaching a contradiction works and this technique is called [proof by contradiction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).

It's likely that your professor starts with certain statements called [*axioms*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom), for example the [Peano axioms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) for natural numbers. But these are foundations of mathematics and reasonings shouldn't try to prove them.

Comment: Hey thanks for your time. I figured out the word it's 'Ansatz

Answer (score 0):

...confirmation bias?

I'm sort of teasing with that answer. Perhaps he is saying "axiom"? Are you doing math? An axiom is a statement that is self-evidently true and then you can draw implications from there.

Comment: Hey thanks for your time. I figured out the word it's 'Ansatz